# How to get ants/termites to attack

Tags: entomology, ant

I am working on ant resistant coatings that are meant to make a material resistant to ants or chewing through them. The question is - how do I get ants to attack the material?

I have considered leaving a plastic bag full of water that is coated in the material outside of an ant hill. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Sugar and grease are strong ant attractors.

Comment: It is possible that a sugar solution could work. I would not have expected grease. Is there a specific type of grease that is the most effective?